# Best way to store a database field that could potentially be a number or string

Tags: database, int, boolean, varchar

We are storing wine data in our database. The vintage of the wine might be a number like **2010** or a string such as **Non-Vintage**.

2010 means the grapes were harvested in 2010.

Non-Vintage means the grapes were harvested across an unknown time-period.

At first we decided to store the field as a string, since 2010 and Non-Vintage are both potentially strings. However, we need to be able to sort the years or perform some arithmetic (i.e. year > 2010).

We are considering either:

- Store the data as a number and "Non-Vintage" would be assigned 0. However, we'd have to provide weird validations everywhere in the app for handling the 0 value.
- Store the year as a number and provide a boolean "non_vintage" field for non-vintage wines.

The data pulled from the database will be delivered to an AngularJS front-end via an API. The Javascript code will have to parse through and use the year at various points... i.e. "show me all wines where year > 2010".

Anyone have any thoughts on which is better and why?

Comment: When you say (perform some arithmetic) you only give an example of a comparitive operator ... the real question is .are you doing any REAL arithmetic?  (ie +, -, *, /  or worse: date "math" )?

Comment: @Ditto updated my question with more pertinent information. And no crazy math... just some comparison like "this year is greater than that year"

Answer (score 0):

are you using mysql?  you can cast strings as ints in your mysql statements.

```
select * from table order by cast(string AS signed) asc;
```

That would mean you can store as a string.

Comment: That's pretty cool; didn't know that. I am using MySQL. However, I am sending the data to be consumed by a JS client. And the JS code isn't going to love getting `year: "2010"` and `year: "NV"`

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Since you're not really treating the year as a number, nor do you need to .. the simplest option you have is to just create a string and have at it.

This has some advantages and disads right off the bat:

Advantage:

- simplest, nothing complex. any database can handle this.
- logic is fairly simple, although a side case to handle your "Non-Vintage" is needed.

Disadvantage:

- potentially allows values you don't want/expect/etc. :
  ie:  "NonVintage", "Non-vantage", "Unknown", "Spider-man!"  ... O.o

This might be mitigated by whatever your process for putting values in might be (ie if it's mostly automated, this might be a smaller issue) :)

========================================

**Option 2**

A more stricter way would be to use 2 columns.
A number and a string.

Store the vintage year in a 4-digit number field, and you know it'll always be a "proper" year. (you could add a check constraint to prevent years < 1000 if you want ;) )

Store the code "NV" in a 2 (or 3?) digit string "code" column. This gives you good flexibility going forward in case other requirements in future start asking for additional types or such.

You could just do a boolean - it would work, however, if things changed in future (they always do), you'd have to redesign .. the string code column has no real hard disad on the boolean and gives you simple flexibility going forward ;)

========================

It would depend on your system and what you know of it, and how the data's coming in ... but I'd probably lean towards option 2 (number + string) myself.